# Прокрутка значений в VS code, как в инспекторе кода Firefox

Tags: visual-studio-code, firefox, прокрутка

Можно ли в VS code реализовать прокрутку значений как в Firefox при нажатии/удерживании стрелки вверх или низ?

[image: Прокрутка значений в инспекторе кода Firefox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `Emmet`-конфигурацией

1. Открыть `Command Palette`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Ввести `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`
3. В открывшемся JSON файле прописать, например

   ```json
    {
    "key": "ctrl+up",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.incrementNumberByOneTenth",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
   ```
4. Теперь при фокусе на тексте и нажатии на сочетание <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> значение будет увеличиваться на `0.1`.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Для того же самого действия, но для уменьшения значения надо добавить

   ```json
    {
    "key": "ctrl+down",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.decrementNumberByOneTenth",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
   ```
6. Для настройки увелечения/уменьшения на `10`, используются следующие параметры

   - `editor.emmet.action.decrementNumberByTen`
   - `editor.emmet.action.incrementNumberByTen`
7. Для настройки увелечения/уменьшения на `1`, используются следующие параметры

   - `editor.emmet.action.decrementNumberByOne`
   - `editor.emmet.action.incrementNumberByOne`

**UPD**

Добавлю настройку использования только для `css` файлов (пример). В значение под ключ `"when"` допишем условие, которое будет подходить только для файлов стилей с расширением `css` (здесь можно использовать и другие расширения, при необходимости, или писать условия с логическим `ИЛИ`)

```json
{
"key": "ctrl+down",
"command": "editor.emmet.action.decrementNumberByOneTenth",
"when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == css"
}
```

Настройка позволяет избегать конфликтов с переопределением горячих клавиш для различных типов файлов. Плюс, возможность таким образом изменять числовые значения не является актуальной для всего окружения в `VSCode`

Comment: Спасибо за полный, лаконичный ответ, я восхищен

Comment: @SlowCoder пользуйтесь на здоровье=)